# Try a simple captcha in CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to implement a simple captcha in ci4, I try to search a sample code in google and then copas it. But when run the code get result like this. Please help what wrong in my code ?

[image: Result Capture]

My controller is :

```
private function captcha()
{
    $i              = 0;
    $imgHeight      = 80;
    $imgWidth       = 250;
    $randTotal      = 7;
    $randomDots     = 50;
    $randomLines    = 25;
    $font           = realpath('./fonts/monofont.ttf');
    $random         = '';
    $captTextColor  = "0x142864";
    $noiseColor     = "0x142864";
    $fontSize       = $imgHeight * 0.65;
    $random         = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'), 0, 
    $randTotal);
    $image          = @imagecreate($imgWidth, $imgHeight);
    
    $arrTextColor   = $this->hexToRGB($captTextColor);
    $arrNoiseColor  = $this->hexToRGB($noiseColor);
    $bgColor        = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $captTextColor  = imagecolorallocate($image, $arrTextColor['red'], $arrTextColor['green'], $arrTextColor['blue']);
    $imgNoiseColor  = imagecolorallocate($image, $arrNoiseColor['red'], $arrNoiseColor['green'], $arrNoiseColor['blue']);


    // Cetak titik acak di latar belakang gambar
    for ($i = 0; $i < $randomDots; $i++) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0, $imgWidth), mt_rand(0, $imgHeight), 2, 3, $imgNoiseColor);
    }

    // Cetak garis acak di latar belakang gambar
    for ($i = 0; $i < $randomLines; $i++) {
        imageline(
            $image,
            mt_rand(0, $imgWidth),
            mt_rand(0, $imgHeight),
            mt_rand(0, $imgWidth),
            mt_rand(0, $imgHeight),
            $imgNoiseColor
        );
    }

    // Cetak kotak teks dan tambahkan 6 kode huruf captcha
    $textBox    = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $random);
    $x          = ($imgWidth - $textBox[4]) / 2;
    $y          = ($imgHeight - $textBox[5]) / 2;
    $_SESSION['captcha']    = $random;

    // imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $captTextColor, $font, $random);
    imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $captTextColor, $font, $random);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image, null, null);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

Thank you

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `exit;` command after the `imagedestroy($image);` line

Comment: Welcome to SO! As it is currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit it and add more details why and how it works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.